# FTP Permissions & Multiple Files of the Same Name

Tags: crystal-reports, permissions, ftp, business-objects

I'm scheduling CSVs to a remote FTP via a business intelligence tool once a month. Per requirements, the file name should be consistent month to month and the file may or may not be deleted. To check if the BI tool would overwrite the file, I scheduled one for one day and the same report for the next, then monitored the "last modified" date in the FTP.

Surprisingly, both files are sitting next to each other with the same filename and appropriate modified dates. The permissions are set to -CR--M----FTP which I haven't seen before. Each file has the same Owner/Group with a difference string after the owner name.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved - server setting on their end. Unfortunately I don't have any more details for anyone else out there, but know that it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you have the same file names in the same directory? If so, this is not possible. They may be the same name, but you have upper/lowercase letters that may be the same.

I'm not sure what tool you're using to upload/download your Crystal Reports files, but Report Runner Batch does a good job of scheduling and doing batch FTP uploads/downloads with automatic date/time stamping if needed.

http://www.reportrunner.com